# how to get initial data on the extra forms

Tags: django, formset

i've got multiple forms, which i want to pull the same initial data into specific fields 
but only the first formset is doing the job but the rest come blank 
also note that CustomerForm is a modelform

```
CustomerFormset = formset_factory(CustomerForm, extra=2)
form = CustomerFormset(initial=[{'Location':'USA', 'age': 10} ])

    context = {  'form':form }
    return render(request,"Customermanager/SubProcess.html",context)
```

so when the form loads... all the rest of the extra COME BLANK!

i want both my intial plus extra to have the same data 
if i can get some code how to do it. ill beable to fill in the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set different initial values for each form in a formset including the extra forms, you have to pass a list of dictionaries containing the initial data for each form to be rendered.

Something like the following would do :

```
Formset = formset_factory(CustomerForm, extra=2)
formset = FormSet(initial=[{'Location':'USA', 'age': 10} for x in range(3)])
```

You might also be interested in [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#id2).

Comment: thank you very much! it does what i want but produces some forms without any info at the bottom when i remove the extra=2 it only leaves 1 form without info 

so what i did by just guessing i put extra = -1 and it removed the extra form without the field

Comment: @user1778743 Glad it helped.

Comment: small question the extra=-1 i hope this wont affect anything